# Как отследить переключение активного окна через библиотеку Pywin32?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pywin32

Нужно написать Python скрипт который будет отслеживать переключение активного окна используя библиотеку Pywin32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот тут оригинал: https://gist.github.com/keturn/6695625

В `eventTypes` описывается какие события нужно отслеживать и для этого вопроса оставил `win32con.EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS`.

Код ниже отслеживает изменение фокуса окон:

```
# using pywin32 for constants and ctypes for everything else seems a little
# indecisive, but whatevs.
import win32con

import sys
import ctypes
import ctypes.wintypes

user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
ole32 = ctypes.windll.ole32
kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32

WinEventProcType = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(
    None,
    ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE,
    ctypes.wintypes.DWORD,
    ctypes.wintypes.HWND,
    ctypes.wintypes.LONG,
    ctypes.wintypes.LONG,
    ctypes.wintypes.DWORD,
    ctypes.wintypes.DWORD
)


# The types of events we want to listen for, and the names we'll use for
# them in the log output. Pick from
# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318066(v=vs.85).aspx
eventTypes = {
    # win32con.EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND: "Foreground",
    win32con.EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS: "Focus",
    # win32con.EVENT_OBJECT_SHOW: "Show",
    # win32con.EVENT_SYSTEM_DIALOGSTART: "Dialog",
    # win32con.EVENT_SYSTEM_CAPTURESTART: "Capture",
    # win32con.EVENT_SYSTEM_MINIMIZEEND: "UnMinimize"
}

# limited information would be sufficient, but our platform doesn't have it.
processFlag = getattr(win32con, 'PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION', win32con.PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION)
threadFlag = getattr(win32con, 'THREAD_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION', win32con.THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION)


# store last event time for displaying time between events
lastTime = 0


def log(msg):
    print(msg)


def logError(msg):
    print(msg, file=sys.stderr)


def getProcessID(dwEventThread, hwnd):
    # It's possible to have a window we can get a PID out of when the thread
    # isn't accessible, but it's also possible to get called with no window,
    # so we have two approaches.

    hThread = kernel32.OpenThread(threadFlag, 0, dwEventThread)

    if hThread:
        try:
            processID = kernel32.GetProcessIdOfThread(hThread)
            if not processID:
                logError("Couldn't get process for thread %s: %s" % (hThread, ctypes.WinError()))
        finally:
            kernel32.CloseHandle(hThread)

    else:
        errors = ["No thread handle for %s: %s" % (dwEventThread, ctypes.WinError(),)]

        if hwnd:
            processID = ctypes.wintypes.DWORD()
            threadID = user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, ctypes.byref(processID))

            if threadID != dwEventThread:
                logError("Window thread != event thread? %s != %s" % (threadID, dwEventThread))

            if processID:
                processID = processID.value
            else:
                errors.append("GetWindowThreadProcessID(%s) didn't work either: %s" % (hwnd, ctypes.WinError()))
                processID = None
        else:
            processID = None

        if not processID:
            for err in errors:
                logError(err)

    return processID


def getProcessFilename(processID):
    hProcess = kernel32.OpenProcess(processFlag, 0, processID)
    if not hProcess:
        logError("OpenProcess(%s) failed: %s" % (processID, ctypes.WinError()))
        return None

    try:
        filenameBufferSize = ctypes.wintypes.DWORD(4096)
        filename = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(filenameBufferSize.value)
        kernel32.QueryFullProcessImageNameW(hProcess, 0, ctypes.byref(filename),
                                            ctypes.byref(filenameBufferSize))

        return filename.value
    finally:
        kernel32.CloseHandle(hProcess)


def callback(hWinEventHook, event, hwnd, idObject, idChild, dwEventThread, dwmsEventTime):
    global lastTime
    length = user32.GetWindowTextLengthW(hwnd)
    title = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(length + 1)
    user32.GetWindowTextW(hwnd, title, length + 1)

    processID = getProcessID(dwEventThread, hwnd)

    shortName = '?'
    if processID:
        filename = getProcessFilename(processID)
        if filename:
            shortName = '\\'.join(filename.rsplit('\\', 2)[-2:])

    if hwnd:
        hwnd = hex(hwnd)
    elif idObject == win32con.OBJID_CURSOR:
        hwnd = '<Cursor>'

    log("%s:%04.2f\t%-10s\tW:%-8s\tP:%-8d\tT:%-8d\t%s\t%s" % (
        dwmsEventTime, float(dwmsEventTime - lastTime)/1000, eventTypes.get(event, hex(event)),
        hwnd, processID or -1, dwEventThread or -1,
        shortName, title.value
    ))

    lastTime = dwmsEventTime


def setHook(WinEventProc, eventType):
    return user32.SetWinEventHook(
        eventType,
        eventType,
        0,
        WinEventProc,
        0,
        0,
        win32con.WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT
    )


def main():
    ole32.CoInitialize(0)

    WinEventProc = WinEventProcType(callback)
    user32.SetWinEventHook.restype = ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE

    hookIDs = [setHook(WinEventProc, et) for et in eventTypes.keys()]
    if not any(hookIDs):
        print('SetWinEventHook failed')
        sys.exit(1)

    msg = ctypes.wintypes.MSG()
    while user32.GetMessageW(ctypes.byref(msg), 0, 0, 0) != 0:
        user32.TranslateMessageW(msg)
        user32.DispatchMessageW(msg)

    for hookID in hookIDs:
        user32.UnhookWinEvent(hookID)

    ole32.CoUninitialize()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, пойду разбираться.

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)